# Condition for convergence of infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the following:

$Q= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k} $.

What condition is required for $x$ so that $Q$ becomes convergent?

Answer (score 1):

lim sup $ | {\frac {1}{n}}|^{\frac {1}{n} }  = 1.$ hence the series is convergent for all $ x \in (-1,1)  $ .Also it is clear that the sum  converges for $x=-1$ but not for $ x = 1$ .Hence, the series is convergent for all $x \in [-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$\frac{dQ}{dx}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{x^{k-1}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x^{i}}$$ You have now a well know series. Back to $Q$ would give you the answer.

But, by the way, $Q$ is a very well known series.

Comment: Thanks. If $x$ is positive, then $0 \le x <1$ would be the solution. But is it true if $x$ is negative? I would like to know the condition for $x$ when $x$ is negative. Is $-1< x \le 0$ correct?